# MongoDB - how to get fields fill-rates as quickly as possible?

Tags: mongodb, mapreduce, database-performance

We have a very big `MongoDB` collection of documents with some pre-defined fields that can either have a value or not.

We need to gather `fill-rates` of those fields, we wrote a script that goes over all documents and counts fill-rates for each, problem is it takes a long time to process all documents.

Is there a way to use `db.collection.aggregate` or `db.collection.mapReduce` to run such a script server-side?
Should it have significant performance improvements?
Will it slow down other usages of that collection (e.g. holding a major lock)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answering my own question, I was able to migrate my script using a cursor to scan the whole collection, to a map-reduce query, and running on a sample of the collection it seems it's at least twice as fast using the map-reduce.

Here's how the old script worked (in node.js):

```
var cursor = collection.find(query, projection).sort({_id: 1}).limit(limit);
var next = function() {
   cursor.nextObject(function(err, doc) {
      processDoc(doc, next);
   });
};
next();
```

and this is the new script:

```
collection.mapReduce(
    function () {
        var processDoc = function(doc) {
            ...
        };
        processDoc(this);
    },
    function (key, values) {
      return Array.sum(values)
    },
    {
      query : query,
      out: {inline: 1}
    },
    function (error, results) {
      // print results
    }
);
```

processDoc stayed basically the same, but instead of incrementing a counter on a global stats object, I do:

```
emit(field_name, 1);
```

**running old and new on a sample of 100k, old took 20 seconds, new took 8.**

**some notes:**

1. map-reduce's `limit` option doesn't work on sharded collections, I had to query for `_id : { $gte, $lte}` to create the sample size needed.
2. map-reduce's performance boost option: `jsMode : true` doesn't work on sharded collections as well (might have improve performance even more), it might work to run it manually on each shard to gain that feature.

Comment: Still your question is not clear, you have not saying if Aggregate is more fast then MapReduce. Anyway good job!

Comment: I actually don't know because I couldn't find a generic way of migrating from a plain node.js script that processes documents one by one to an aggregate function, the above solution describes how I was able to do so with map-reduce

Answer (score 0):

As I understood what you want to achieve is compute something on your documents, after that you have a new "document" that can be queried. You don't need to store the "new values" computed.

If you don't need to write your "new values" inside that documents, you can use Aggregation Framework.

*Aggregations operations process data records and return computed results. Aggregation operations group values from multiple documents together, and can perform a variety of operations on the grouped data to return a single result.*

https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/aggregation/

Since Aggregation Framework has a lot of features i can't give you more informations about how to resolve your issue.

Comment: thanks, I'm aware of the aggregation framework, as well as the map-reduce technique, my question was specifically about using one of those to calculate fields' fill-rates. also, this doesn't answer my related questions about performance improvements/issues.

Comment: please update your question with the data you have in the collection.

Comment: thanks, I was successful at rewriting my script using map-reduce, see my answer below.